# Get 'balanced' column value as 'Y' if both rows has same amt and 'N' if not in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have number of CR records and DR records against the same id , 
I need to check sum of DR amount matches with the sum of CR amount for the same id if CR matches with DR then display Balanced column as "Y" else "N"

Required Result: Balanced" column value 'Y' if the Credit and Debit amt column matches and 'N' if they mismatch

Note: single query is needed for this:

[image]

As shown in above screen grab red highlighted result is required .

Script is given below :

```
USE [data]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BankData]    Script Date: 04-05-2018 3.54.46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BankData](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Amt] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Type] [char](10) NULL,
    [TransId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustId] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customer]    Script Date: 04-05-2018 3.54.46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CustId] [int] NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (1, N'YASH      ', CAST(300 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'DR        ', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (1, N'YASH      ', CAST(300 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'CR        ', 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (2, N'FALE      ', CAST(120 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'DR        ', 3, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (2, N'FALE      ', CAST(140 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'CR        ', 4, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (3, N'RAHUL     ', CAST(100 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'CR        ', 5, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (3, N'RAHUL     ', CAST(100 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'DR        ', 6, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (4, N'DINESH    ', CAST(900 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'CR        ', 7, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (4, N'DINESH    ', CAST(900 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'DR        ', 8, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (2, N'FALE      ', CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'DR        ', 9, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[BankData] ([ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId]) VALUES (2, N'FALE      ', CAST(130 AS Decimal(18, 0)), N'DR        ', 10, 2)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BankData] OFF
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustId], [Address]) VALUES (1, N'Mumbai')
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustId], [Address]) VALUES (2, N'Delhi')
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustId], [Address]) VALUES (3, N'Pune')
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustId], [Address]) VALUES (4, N'Banglore')
INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([CustId], [Address]) VALUES (5, N'Surat')
```

Comment: Please show the query that you have written to try to solve this problem.

Comment: This looks more like a project brief than a question. Stackoverflow is a question and answer site, not a free code writing service. You will elicit a more positive response if you try and tackle the problem yourself, and come back with more specific questions if you encounter problems.

Comment: yes i tried but failed to use logic what exactly do here in this situation , To ignore editing questions multiple time i have posted sql db script that i am using .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 2012+, this is a small matter using the window function `sum() over`

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Balanced = IIF(sum(Amt * IIF([Type]='CR',-1,1)) over (Partition By ID) =0,'Y','N')
 from [BankData]
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name    Amt Type    TransId CustId  Balanced
1   YASH        300 DR          1   1   Y
1   YASH        300 CR          2   1   Y
2   FALE        120 DR          3   2   N
2   FALE        140 CR          4   2   N
2   FALE        30  DR          9   2   N
2   FALE        130 DR          10  2   N
3   RAHUL       100 CR          5   3   Y
3   RAHUL       100 DR          6   3   Y
4   DINESH      900 CR          7   4   Y
4   DINESH      900 DR          8   4   Y
```

Comment: Thanks its working . Can you add explanation for above code ?

Comment: @Tiger the window functions can be invaluable.  It is well worth your time to get comfortable with them

Answer (score 1):

I use in-query to get the Balanced column. I group by ID then get the sum of Amt. If type is CR then it is negative (-1*Amt) and if DR it is positive. Then I did a query for table bankData and assign it to it's own ID (t1.ID=t.ID).  If sum is zero then it is balanced='Y' else it is not ('N').

```
select [ID], [Name], [Amt], [Type], [TransId], [CustId],
(select case when sum(case when [Type]='DR' then [Amt] else -1*[Amt] end)=0 
   then 'Y' 
   else 'N' end 
from [dbo].[BankData] as t1
where t1.[ID] = t.[ID]
group by t1.[ID]) as Balanced
from [dbo].[BankData] as t
order by t.[ID], t.[TransId]
```